# How I do read what john already did / how far he progressed?

Tags: john-the-ripper

I let the app run since around 2 days.
The app tells me to press q to quit and any other key to show the status.
I do that from time to time.

However, I do not understand how to read what I am seeing.

I expected the string to get longer and longer, but - as I understood it - their lenghts vary.

I am also confused because the start of the string looks very similar (but not identical) for the end of the string. And I don't understand the ".."

How do I know what it is just doing and how far it has progressed?
I didn't find the documentation for this.

[image]

Comment: `proceeding with wordlist:password.lst` - so you're using a wordlist.

Comment: And what do the words at the end of each line mean?

Comment: The linked duplicate explains that